# Steam error when adding friends

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I've got few problems in Steam, where I can't add friends. I'm trying to add my first Steam friend but it comes up with one of these messages:

"Could not invite %s. Their friends list is full."

[image: Error message 1]

[image: Error message 2]

Does anyone know what the problem is, and how to fix it?

Comment: Thats it i need pay money for adding friends UGHHHH!! >:(

Comment: or is there a way to break the rules to invite a friend instead?

Comment: Erm, the error message already says it all: "*Their friends list is full.*" You'll have to ask them to remove some of their "friends" so you can add them (or they can add you). There's nothing else you can do.

Comment: And this is why most popular youtubers/streamers/whatever don't randomly accept friend requests.

Comment: As everyone's said, the clue's in the error message. If you know them, ask them to remove someone/increase their friends list size (Can be done via Steam levels) If you don't know them... well, chances are they aren't going to accept your invite anyway :P

Comment: There is the community badge which you can make by solving community tasks and which will give you- i think - up to 300 EPX. If your friend cant delete anyone and if he is lowleveled its likely that he can increase his steam level with that badge.

Comment: I saw another post its saying you need pay 5$ US dollars for making the premissions. Since im european i think they havent updated their servers

Answer (score 6):

Friendslist of people are limited and only goes up by leveling up. That person has it filled, so you can't add him/her unless s/he levels up or unfriends someone.

Comment: Aka. You can do nothing about it.